# Movie Play Does Not Work In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, video-player

I could play all of my DVDs in 16.04 LTS, but since upgrading to 18.04.1 LTS it will play none of the DVDs.  I checked the various libdvd packages and they are all current as well as the ubuntu restricted packages.  Any ideas?

Edit: libdvdcss2/now 1.4.2-1~local amd64 [installed,local]

Comment: Can you add the output of `apt list libdvdcss2` to your question?

Comment: I am not a gearhead.  What commands do I put in the terminal to get the apt output?  Thanks.

Comment: In the terminal, execute the command `apt list libdvdcss2` - then highlight the text with your mouse and press ctrl+shift+c to copy the text.  In the question above, click on 'edit' and press ctrl+v to paste the text into your question.

Comment: libdvdcss2/now 1.4.2-1~local amd64 [installed,local]

Here's what I get, above.

Comment: Btw, see my answer below.  You don't say whether your setup works for other video formats.  Are you trying to play from a physical DVD, or an .iso or a compressed movie file?

Comment: I have been trying to play a physical DVD.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of the things stopping you, may be a need for

```
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt install -y libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

The reconfigure step needs to be done...

Comment: I have both of those but appears that I need to do the reconfig.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, did that, but it did not work.

Comment: See my comment and answer, too. OP may need all the plugins (and probably a different player). But should try `sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg`

Comment: I followed all steps---thanks for your patience, but nothing worked.  It seems Movie player is just plain broken.  I can view the DVD using VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another player? I thought the default player in 18 was broken. Try VLC, e.g.,

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Or your choice.

Btw, the advice from @charles_green can be extended as follows:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
```

To get all the DVD -bad and -ugly codecs . . .

Let us know.

Comment: I got the gstreamer bad and uglies. no deal with movie player.  However, VLC works.  So, Movie player must be busted in Ubuntu 18.  Thanks so much guys.

Comment: You're welcome.  Those gstreamer bad and uglies are needed at any rate for VLC too, so no real wasted efforts except you confirm the player wuz broken. Pls mark my answer as correct please, then (or at least helpful!)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens while upgrading ubuntu.
You may try these libdvd packages plus some more packages needed by this command

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg

sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```